# 301 Redirect URL Appending Query String

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

From last 3 hours, I'm trying this 301 url redirect but its not working as expected. Please help me with this. here is the .htaccess file code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
rewriterule ^deals/(.*)$ details.php?id=$1 [L]
rewritecond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} publisher.php

Redirect 301 /deals/74/product-name.html http://mydomain.com/74/product-name.html
```

Whenever I enter www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html, It redirects me to "www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html?id=74&name=product-name"

I'm not sure why its appending "?id=74&name=product-name" after url? I want to display only "www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html"

I don't know how to fix this problem. I'll appreciate if you can guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to everyone who responded and tried to help me. It took approx. the whole day to figure out myself the solution. I hope my answer will help someone,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^deals/74/product-name.html$ 74/product-name.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2


rewritecond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} publisher.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ publisher.php [L]
```

I took the last line "RewriteRule ^deals/74/product-name.html$ 74/product-name.html [R=301,L]" and pasted above all Rewrite Rules and it worked. I guess it was overlapping with some other Rewrite rules. But finally, its working as I expected.

Thanks to Everyone again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using `(.*)/(.*)`.

This is what I always use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

All URLs start checked and rewrited by PHP (or use nginx if you want speed), but .htaccess must be clean. Simple for read, simple for rewrite (to nginx or another server).

index.php:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) != 'www.'){
    $protocol = (substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cgi' ? 'Status:' : $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);

    header($protocol.' 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    exit;
}

// Simple path checker
$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
$path = pathinfo($uri);

// Check

if ($path['extension'] == '.html'){
    $_GET['id'] = $path['dirname'];
    $_GET['name'] = $path['filename'];

    include 'product.php';
    exit;
}

if ($path['dirname'] == 'deals'){
    $_GET['id'] = $path['filename']; 

    include 'details.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: lexa, thanks for the reply but I', using .htaccess file on LAMP server. I guess "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" is used in web.config file for windows server. Also I don't wanna modify PHP files just want to 301 redirect using .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Redirect directive docs at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

There you can see that:

> If the client requests http://example.com/service/foo.txt, it will be told to access 
>   http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.txt instead. This includes requests with GET parameters, 
>   such as http://example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42, it will be redirected to 
>   http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42. Note that POSTs will be discarded.

The last rule in your config is:

```
Redirect 301 /deals/74/product-name.html http://mydomain.com/74/product-name.html
```

mod_alias will append all GET parameters

If you don't want the GET parameters to be appended, maybe you might change the Redirect rule for a Rewrite rule
Something like:

```
Rewrite ^/deals/74/product-name.html http://mydomain.com/74/product-name.html [R=301]
```

Easy

Comment: Hello futuretelematics, thanks for the reply. I tried rewrite but its not working.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your help. I figured out the solution and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why its appending "?id=74&name=product-name" after url?

It is doing so because your URI `/deals/74/product-name.html` is matching both these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

and

```
Redirect 301 /deals/74/product-name.html http://mydomain.com/74/product-name.html
```

It is **not a good idea to mix** mod_alias and mod_rewrite together. Better to use mod_rewrite itself for finer and granular control.

Your modified .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^deals/(74/product-name\.html)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/74/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^deals/(.*)$ /details.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /publisher.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello anubhava, Thanks for reply. I tried your code but its not working. it shiws page now found and all pages stop working.

Comment: @prototype: If you notice this suggested .htaccess is 90% taken from your own own .htaccess. I just corrected and changed order of one `/deals/74` URL which CANNOT make all your URLs not working. My guess is its most likely your `/publisher.php` that is causing all the trouble and that I don't even know why its there since it redirects all http traffic to `/publisher.php`. Try commenting that and then retry.

Comment: Let me check and I'll let you know

Comment: still not working. its still appending those variable strings

Comment: Yes that is because after redirect `/74/product-name\.html` still matches `^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$`

Comment: hello anubhava, thanks for the help. I somehow fixed the problem. Take a look, I posted the answer. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: That looks similar to my answer + my comment on taking care of `publisher.php` rule :P If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.